# Fetching external API with Spring Boot returning 400 bad request after app restart

Tags: java, .net, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot as API gateway for my application and I have this weird issue - when I restart the app (sometimes it happens even often) and call my endpoint (for example: `/api/all`), which should return parsed and formatted data from external API, first external API call return 400 Bad Request Status. I don't know if this is a problem with their backend or mine, but when I call their endpoint in postman, it works just fine.

What I found is that they have probably some .NET backend (by searching returned error message), but I am not sure if this helps you.

**Here is the 400 response**
[image: Here is the 400 response]

**And here is the 200 response**
[image: And here is the 200 response]

**And this is the error message returned from their backend**
[image: And this is the error message returned from their backend]

Also, I am using `compile group: 'com.hynnet', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.1'` for fetching external API.

Here is my POST request builder method

```
public static HttpRequest buildPostRequest(final String url, final String body) {
    return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_1_1)
            .uri(URI.create(url))
            .setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON)
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(body))
            .build();
}
```

This is my POST request sender method

```
public HttpResponse<String> sendPostRequest(
        final LinkedHashMap<String, Object> bodyStructure,
        final String url)
        throws Exception {
    final String body = buildBody(bodyStructure);
    final HttpRequest request = buildPostRequest(url, body);

    return client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
}
```

And this is my CacheService (It just cache response from the external API, when it fails, it tries it again one second later). **BTW. this approach works just fine and on the second call, it returns 200 OK response.**

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = TRANSPORT_LOCATIONS, cacheManager = CACHE_MANAGER, key = ROOT_METHOD_NAME)
public HttpResponse<String> getTransportsLocations(
        final LinkedHashMap<String, Object> bodyStructure,
        final String url)
        throws Exception {
    HttpResponse<String> response = requestSender.sendPostRequest(bodyStructure, url);

    if (response.statusCode() != OK_STATUS) {
        LOG.error(GET_TRANSPORT_LOCATION_BAD_REQUEST_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Thread.sleep(FALLBACK_TIMEOUT);
        response = requestSender.sendPostRequest(bodyStructure, url);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Do you have any idea, where the problem should be?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check difference of the paremeter which you send,It looks like api side return bad request.

What‘s more you can try to save repsonsebody in one html file which will more easy
to read the response information.

By the way ,I noted the second call‘s header has “access-control-allow-origin :*“,

In Springboot you can use @CrossOrigin ,on Controller to CROS

Comment: I don't think that problem is in the CORS... And since I know, this annotation will allow CORS for my endpoints, it won't add any to the request that I am making to call external API.

Comment: “access-control-allow-origin :*“ means all of cross call, you can only add what you need  e.g. "access-control-allow-origin : https://google/api/token"

Comment: Yes, I know, but included screenshots are responses from external API, they have to set, from which domain they allow access. They set this wildcard, because it is public API I guess.

Comment: emm, if you don't  think CROS issue, how about check the different of  host name ? As We could see the tips of  “Invalid hostname”